# Axios - How to add default header to all custom axios instances?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to add auth header when user logged in. I'm able to update base axios instance but I can't update custom instances like `settingsApi` etc..

```js
import baseAxios from "axios";
import {csrfToken} from "../helpers";

baseAxios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken();
baseAxios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";

export const setAuthToken = token => {
    baseAxios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token
};

export const settingsApi = baseAxios.create({
    baseURL: "/api/settings"
});
...
```

`setAuthToken` only updates baseAxios, it has no effect on custom instances which initialized at the first place. To make it work, I have to add auth header all custom instances individually, is there any elegant way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `settingsApi` instance has been created in the first time when you import your helper module. At that time,  `setAuthToken` function did not be called, then `baseAxios` does not have `Authorization` header.

My suggestion, make `settingsApi` to be an function, then each times when you need to use `settingsApi`, it will return a instance what created by "newest" `baseAxios`.

```
import baseAxios from "axios";
import {csrfToken} from "../helpers";

baseAxios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken();
baseAxios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";

export const setAuthToken = token => {
    baseAxios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token
};

// Make it to be a function
export const getSettingsApi = () => baseAxios.create({
    baseURL: "/api/settings"
});

// ...
```